# Express.js application bug: delete post route is not found

Tags: express, mean-stack

I am working on a **[blogging application](https://github.com/Ajax30/XPressBlog)** (click the link to see the **GitHub** repo) with [Express](https://expressjs.com/), [EJS](https://ejs.co/) and MongoDB.

I have been unable to delete a post via AJAX.

In my **Dashboard** routes file (`routes\admin\dashboard.js`) I have:

```
// Delete Post
router.delete('/post/delete/:id', dashboardController.deletePost);
```

In my **Dashboard** controller:

```
exports.deletePost = (req, res, next) => {
    const postId = req.params.id;
    posts.findByIdAndRemove(postId, function(err){
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error: ', err);
        }
        res.sendStatus(200);
    });
}
```

In the view that lists the post in a table, with and "Edit" and a "Delete" button for each one I have:

```
<% if (posts) { %>
    <% posts.forEach(function(post) { %>
        <tr data-id="<%= post._id %>" class="d-flex">
            <td class="col-1"></td>
            <td class="col-4 col-lg-5">
                <%= post.title %>
            </td>
            <td class="col-2"></td>
            <td class="col-2"></td>
            <td class="col-3 col-lg-2 text-right">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Edit</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger delete-post" data-id="<%= post._id %>">Delete</a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <% }); %>
<% } else { %>
        <tr>
           <td colspan="5">There are no posts</td>
        </tr>
<% } %>
```

Finally in `public\assets\js\admin.js` I have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.delete-post').on('click', function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    let postId = $(this).data('id');
    if(confirm('Delete this post?')) {
      $.ajax({
        url: '/post/delete/' + postId,
        method: 'GET',
        success: function(deleteMsg){
          $('tr[data-id="' + postId +'"]').fadeOut('250');
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

I have that was enough for the delete operation to be successful, but it is not.

**UPDATE:**

If I replace `url: '/post/delete/' + postId,` with `url: '/dashboard/post/delete/' + postId,` I get a `500 internal server error`. I see `posts is not defined` in the network tab.

What am I missing?

Comment: you are using the router method `delete` but the ajax call is a `GET`?

Comment: @josh.trow If I use delete I just get `Cannot DELETE /post/delete/5e5cfc7604083c083465f47c` instead of `Cannot GET /post/delete/5e5cfc7604083c083465f47c`.

Comment: What is your main server.js or whatever? Are you sure you have your dashboard router correctly being setup on the app?

Comment: @josh.trow Yes, I am sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue this way:

1) I replaced `posts.findByIdAndRemove` with `Post.findByIdAndRemove`:

```
exports.deletePost = (req, res, next) => {
    const postId = req.params.id;
    Post.findByIdAndRemove(postId, function(err){
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error: ', err);
        }
        res.sendStatus(200);
    });
}
```

2) I replaced `url: '/post/delete/' + postId,` with `url: '/dashboard/post/delete/' + postId,` in my jQuery snippet.

Comment: your original question was related to delete route not found, I am glad that i was of some help figuring out the correct route to hit.

Answer (score 1):

**I did it like this**, for complete running example clone **updated** [node-cheat XPressBlog](https://github.com/zishon89us/node-cheat/tree/master/stackoverflow_answers/express-loading-stuck/XPressBlog-master) and run node index followed by `npm i`.

added `delete` to *routes/front-end/posts.js*, like:

```
// Delete Single Post
router.delete('/:id', postsController.deleteSinglePost);
```

added `deleteSinglePost` to *controllers/front-end/posts.js*, like:

```
exports.deleteSinglePost = (req, res, next) => {
    const {id} = req.params;
    res.send(`This will DELETE post with id : ${id}`);
};
```

This is done based on looking at `index.js`, that is:

```
const dashboardRoute = require("./routes/admin/dashboard");
app.use('/dashboard', dashboardRoute);

const postsRoute = require('./routes/front-end/posts');
app.use('/', postsRoute);
```

*curl -X DELETE http://localhost:3000/100*:

> This will DELETE post with id : 100

Comment: I deed to *add*, *edit* and *delete* in the back-end (from the dashboard).

Comment: then add above code in dashboard route and controller respectively and then url will become  http://localhost:3000/dashboard/100 because your code is configured that way.

Comment: /post/delete/5e5cfc7604083c083465f47c should be dashboard/post/delete/5e5cfc7604083c083465f47c

Comment: I did: I just get Cannot DELETE /post/delete/5e5cfc7604083c083465f47c instead of Cannot GET /post/delete/5e5cfc7604083c083465f47c.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208856/discussion-between-zeeshan-hassan-memon-and-razvan-zamfir).

Comment: If I replace `url: '/post/delete/' + postId,` with `url: '/dashboard/post/delete/' + postId,` I get a `500 internal server error. I see `posts is not defined` in the network tab.

Comment: lets chat here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208856/discussion-between-zeeshan-hassan-memon-and-razvan-zamfir